# Python update the Set

Tags: python, set

The code below return this:

```
Person A have friends ['B', 'A']
Person B have friends ['B', 'A']
```

But it is intended to return:

```
Person A have friends ['B']
Person B have friends ['A']
```

"A" must reference "B" and vice-versa. But "A" is referencing "B" and "A", why?

**CODE:**

```
class person:
    name = ""
    friends = set()

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add(self, new):
        self.friends |= {new}
        new.friends |= {self}
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
pa = person("A")
pb = person("B")

pa.add(pb)

print( "Person", pa.name, "have friends", [f.name for f in pa.friends] )
print( "Person", pb.name, "have friends", [f.name for f in pb.friends] )
```

Comment: I would suggest reading through [Python's great documentation on classes](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class person:
    name = ""
    friends = set()
```

With this construct, the `friends` set is an attribute on the *classobject* `person`.  This means the same set is shared between each instance.  In your `add` method, `self.friends` and `new.friends` is literally the same object.

To change the friends set to an instance variable:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.friends = set()

    def add(self, new):
        self.friends |= {new}
        new.friends |= {self}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `friends` as a class variable. You can declare it in the scope of the instance by setting it in `__init__`:

```
class person:
    name = ""
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.friends = set()
        self.name = name

    def add(self, new):
        self.friends |= {new}
        new.friends |= {self}
```